# Does inorganic particles have pattern recognition receptor?

Tags: immunity

Does silica or carbon particles (inorganic substances causing silicosis and anthracosis) have Pattern Recognition Receptor (PRR) on macrophages/dendritic cells? Because phagocytic activity depends on PRR. If it doesn't have how it engulfs it?

Comment: Pinocytosis....

Comment: I think that I have posted this link for you before [NIH Bookshelf: Janeway's Immunobiology](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10757/). You are continually asking questions on this site about immunology that would be answered if you simply read this book (even though this edition is slightly out of date). It is a **free resource** and it will explain everything you are looking to find out, and then some, about the basics of immunology. The only annoyance is that in order to read you need to enter a search term, you cannot read cover to cover like a normal book.